# Is the HEAP a term for ram, processor memory or BOTH? And how many unions can I allocate for at once?

Tags: c++, stack

I was hoping someone had some schooling they could lay down about the whole HEAP and stack ordeal. I am trying to make a program that would attempt to create about 20,000 instances of just one union and if so some day I may want to implement a much larger program. Other than my current project consisting of a maximum of just 20,000 unions stored where ever c++ will allocate them do you think I could up the anti into the millions while retaining a reasonable return speed on function calls, approximately 1,360,000 or so? And how do you think it will handle 20,000?

Comment: I think you should try it, rather than ask here if it will work.  After all, trying things is a large part of where experience comes from.

Comment: Try it. And read up on CPU architecture etc. heap has nothing to do with processor memory (you may mean cache? ) You are probably better off trying and reading about those things if you want to learn it.

Comment: This depends if your situation is a right-to-work or if it allows for mandatory unions.  The union overhead will vary depending on that and other context.

Answer (score 1):

Heap is an area used for dynamic memory allocation.

It's usually used to allocate space for variable collection size, and/or to allocate a large amount of memory. It's definitely not a CPU register(s).

Besides this I think there is no guarantee what heap is.

This may be RAM, may be processor cache, even HDD storage. Let OS and hardware decide what it will be in particular case.

Comment: I'm also fairly confident the C++ standard does not require a `stack` and a `heap` to be a thing.

Comment: @Asu: Well, there's `std::stack<Foo>` and `std::make_heap` but that is probably not what's intended.

Comment: a `stack` is just a data structure, it does not imply you need a stack and a heap in your implementation (even if it's not dynamically allocated on most implementations). same goes for `make_heap`